# Bluetooth Complexity

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth

I want, users of my Domain can not pass or transfer any file via Bluetooth due to Data Leakage issue in my office. But They can able to use Bluetooth TWS / Bluetooth sound systems. How can i do this?

Maximum tutorial I found is about direct block bluetooth. Here my case is different and something complex. If I block fsquirt.exe then whole bluetooth system will be shutdown.

Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: Bluetooth is for personal devices (mouse, keyboard, headset) and not for transferring files. What different are you trying to do?

Comment: @John, sorry to tell you this but you are wrong here.  [Bluetooth is also for transferring files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-files-over-bluetooth-36f8cf26-d1ff-50d1-4b73-3a56e5b43e6a). It was one of the first profiles implemented using something Bluetooth calls [OBEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles).  I was writing code for it when Bluetooth 1.0 was still in beta.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.  We do not do this in any of our customers.

Comment: The question is unclear: What are you trying to block, or how do you want to transfer files, and what have sound systems to do with all this?

Comment: I want to block file share only but voice or music can run via bluetooth headphones or TWS.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling fsquirt.exe should not shut down everything.  It is responsible for file transfer only.

The bluetooth profile you want to disable is called OBEX and there is indeed a way to disable specific profiles in Windows.. unfortunately.. the REAL way to do it seems to be mostly undocumented.

[This link points to data that shows that the mechanism exists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-bluetooth#bluetooth-servicesallowedlist) and uses CSPs (configuration service providers) through windows client management.  I know NOTHING about CSPs.. I am not an admin.  If you DO, I would use the section in the middle of the link above to enable only the BT profiles that you want.  Search that page for OBEX and you will find your stuff!

I did quite a bit of research on this (just now) and it also looks like the implementation is still a moving target.

I ***DID*** find your fsquirt.exe solution that should have worked for you.

```
How do I unhook Fsquirt.exe?
Software developers that desire to replace the in-box Bluetooth File Transfer Wizard with a proprietary application can unhook Fsquirt.exe from the underlying transfer wizard mechanism by performing the following steps:

* Create a DWORD value that is named DisableFsquirt under the HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Bthport\Parameters key in the registry.
* Set the value of DisableFsquirt to 0x1
* Either reboot or run the following command in a command prompt window: fsquirt.exe -UnRegister
```

This information  [came from MS here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/bluetooth-user-interface) .

It should work.
In the future, we will probably (hopefully) have a less stupid solution.

Good luck!
Please let me know if it worked. :)

Comment: I am still working on a better solution.  The registry is complicated for this one.. all UUIDs! (yuck!)